# Checking a function input is supplied in R

Tags: r

I have the following (pointless) function, in `R`:

```
say <- function (string){
  if(!exists("string")){
    stop("no output string was specified")
  }
  cat(string)
}
```

Which is all very well at checking the string object actually exists.  However, if an object of the same name is already floating about in the workspace, it'll ignore the error even though that's not defined in the function.

Can I make it so the exists() function only looks in the function-space for the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `missing`.  Others do something like this instead:

```
say <- function(string=NULL){
  if(is.null(string)){
    stop("no output string was specified")
  }
  cat(string)
}
```

Comment: i.e. `if(missing(string)) stop()`

Comment: what are the advantages of `is.null` versus `missing`?

Comment: @Xu: it is possible to have a variable in existence whose value is NULL, so it depends on exactly what you want to do with the variable, basically.

Comment: Edit: IIRC @jbaums' construct fails if you write `function(string=NULL)`, so use `function(string)` , i.e. no default value.